# Animations being fired on page load

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm experiencing an issue with the css **transitions** firing on page load. Basically there were a problem with fancy links with custom background dropping from the top(start position) on the page load.
You can see example [here](http://k5.ru/fogetable/test).

These problems only occur if there is both **input** and **a** tags on the page so if we remove input everything will be just fine. The other way to solve this problem is not to use an external css file: it works fine with [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lafejibovu/edit?html,css,output), but it isn't really helps because I want to understand why this things could ever be happening.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signin.css">
    <title>Dobrotech</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="password" name="password" required=""/>
    <a href="">forgot password?</a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    background: url(/dobro.tech/images/link.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    background-size: 70% 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background: url(/dobro.tech/images/activelink.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    background-size: 70% 12px;
}

a {
    transition: background-size 0.5s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
}

a:hover {
    transition: background-size 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear;
}
```

---

UPDATE: I've decided to remake this link effect using ::before pseudoclass and the problem is gone but I still want to figure out what cause links and inputs interact that weirdely

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
a{
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
background: url(dobro.tech/images/link.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
background-size: 70% 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
background: url(dobro.tech/images/activelink.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
background-size: 70% 12px;
}
```

i remove first **/** from background url

[download my sample](http://s5.picofile.com/d/8287257384/c78e5788-061e-468e-9c18-88237a2a69dd/testHTML.rar)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't work for me. the /dobro.tech is equal to C:/dobro.tech. Even the external links to img like [this](https://pp.vk.me/c638630/v638630595/257aa/NivvXatQk-k.jpg) won't help.